# Multiple square brackets in python

Tags: python, brackets

```
    def startpop(pop,job):
       i = 0 
       L = [[[(random.uniform(1,0))]]] 
       while i < pop:
          k = 0 
          if len(L) <= i:
          L.append([[random.uniform(1,0)]])
```

I'm trying to understand this code. What is the meaning of three square brackets?

Comment: That is just a list of list of lists

Comment: list in list  in list ..... it does not mean anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it simply a list in a list in a list:

```
[
    [
       [
           (random.uniform(1,0))
       ]
    ]
 ]
```

i.e.

```
>>> test = [[[1,2]]]
>>> print test[0]
[[1,2]]
>>> print test[0][0]
[1,2]
>>> print test[0][0][0]
1
```